# How to get/store the elements of a ng-repeat in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

There is a list of elements inside a div which are shown as a list (one under the other) and I want to get those elements and show them on the same line (one near the other).

The parent looks like:

```
<div class="table-option table-option__items">
    <div ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.configuration" class = "table-option-item">
        <div class="table-option-header">   
            {{option.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can access it in console( and also in .js file) by

`var parent = $(".table-option__items")[0];`

and each of the children by

`var child = $(".table-option-item")[i];` , `i` being its index.

In my case there are 4 children so I can access them by replacing i with 0,1,2 or 3. I don't know how to get the length of the parent too.

I want to be able to access all the children from the parent like looping through the parent and being able to do operations on the children. To have them in a list/array/object or something like that.

In my particular case to change their order from vertically one under the other to put them one near the other horizontally. 
Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need any of this? ng-repeat iterates over an array and you should access/manipulate DOM through that array. Mixing angular and jquery will be no good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're a beginner at angularjs but have used jQuery before. Angularjs uses jQuery (or when not included on the page, a specific small subset of it) "behind the scenes", and if you are trying to write good-form angularjs code,you should only ever use jQuery yourself when writing custom angularjs [`directives`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). This is the design of angular, so that no DOM manipulation is mixed with the business logic of your app. Here's a quick example on how to re-jigger your ng-repeat loop in a more angular way:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.options = [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}]
})
```

```css
.quux{
  display: inline-block;
}
.thing{
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="quux" ng-repeat="option in options">
        <span class="thing">   
            {{option.name}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for finding total length then
u can use .length with just a descendant selector, like this:

```
var count = $(".table-option-item").length;
```

If you have to use .children(), then it's like this:

```
var count = $(".table-option div").children().length;
var length = $('.table-option__items').children('div').length
```